# How to make java Method Class for sms gateway use HTTP protocol for communication beetween data

Tags: java, methods, sms, gateway

This is about sms gateway for enterprise. We'll Have 3 vendor sms gateway. I want to make method class that can send sms use url from each vendor. can you tell me how to make a method class as example follows:

```
void sendSmsToXXX (String phonenumber, String message) {
// Send to XXX, which is xxx is one of three sms gateway vendor.
}
```

For send HTTP GET requests in java we can using HttpURLConnection class. Then one of 3 vendor message require messages to be encoded hearts hexa Decimal, please use DatatypeConverter class.

and I have make a simulator at IP 10.213.5.86 ip port simulator in 8085.
for Example URL and parameter request is:
http://10.213.5.86:8085/sms/send/jatis?userid=JATIS&password=JATISabcd&msisdn=62857712345&message=tes kirim http GET&sender=SENDERJATIS&division=Marketing&batchname=test&uploadby=rangga&channel=2